# Plot Two Regression Lines on Same Scatter Plot By Year: X-Axis Date MM/DD

Tags: date, group-by, sas, regression, sgplot

I have a scatter plot of calls / time. My x variable is the date (Day/Month) and my Y variable is a number of calls on each date. I would like to plot two regression lines using PROC SGPLOT REG, one for 2019 and one for 2020. However, when I try to do this, all I get is a regular scatter plot with no regression lines. Here is my code:

```
 proc sgplot data=intern.bothphase1;
 reg x=date y=count / group=Year;
 label count="Calls Per Day" year="Year";
 Title "Comparison of EMS Calls per Day 1/1 - 3/31 in 2019 vs. 
 2020";
 run;
```

The scatter plot comes up without issue (2019 and 2020 values in different colors) but I want to see how the trends differed between the two time periods, so I really want to get the regression lines on there. Can anyone help?

I imagine this has to do with the fact that I concatenated my day and month with a / so it is a character variable and so SAS cannot calculate the regression. I did this so I could use year as a class variable. I still have the original date variable in my table, is there a way I could get SAS to give me the month/day from that as a numeric variable?

Thanks!

EDIT: I used a date value in SAS and changed the format to mm/dd, but this doesn't help because the regression lines are just on either end of the graph rather than overlapping (picture attached). [what I want is to have the regression lines overlap for the same time period 2019 vs. 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLQT8.png) This is because SAS dates correspond to numbers from 1/1/1960. What I want is the mm/dd to correspond to numbers 1-365 so I get two overlapping regression lines to show how the trends changed from one year to the next. Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You cannot do regression with character variables so you're right there. Convert it to a SAS date and apply a format to it. You can have a new variable that has the year or even restructure your data so that you have different years in different columns.

Comment: A date value with format `mmddyy5.` will appear as `mm/dd`.  So compute a date value if necessary, and use that for x.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the help, but this didn't work.  Since dates in SAS are number of days since 1/1/1960, changing the format didn't help. What I need the mm/dd to correlate to are numbers 1-365 so the regression lines overlap. Any ideas on how I could do this?  I will attach a picture of my problem to the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

So two steps here: first, you need to generate a "day" value that's 1-365... so let's just subtract out 01JAN from the day value.

```
data have;
  do date = '01JAN2019'd to '31DEC2020'd;
    count = 25+2*rand('uniform');
    year = year(date);
    if month(date) le 3 then output;
  end;  
  format date date9.;
run;

data adjusted;
  set have;
  date_fixed = date - intnx('year',date,0,'b') + 1;  *current date minus jan 1 plus 1 (otherwise off by 1);
  format date_fixed date5.;                          *this does not actually affect the graph axis, oddly;
run;


 proc sgplot data=adjusted;
 reg x=date_fixed y=count / group=Year;
 xaxis valuesformat=date5.;                   *this seems to be needed for some reason;
 label count="Calls Per Day" year="Year";
 Title "Comparison of EMS Calls per Day 1/1 - 3/31 in 2019 vs. 
 2020";
 run;
```

Then we add the `xaxis` line because for some reason it won't obey the `DATE5.` format (could also use `MMDDYY5.` as Reeza noted in comments, but we can force it to here.

Here is what I get. You can use other axis options to further limit things, so for example 01APR doesn't show up.

[image: regression image showing blue and red lines over a scatterplot overlaid, with a single axis showing 01JAN-01APR])

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I had some trouble with the do statement, however. It created a million observations from my original set of 900. Not sure what I did wrong? I ended up finding the following code to get my date variable: DayOfYear = date - intnx('year', date, 0, 'b') + 1;